# A simple http request on android, no idea why get error

Tags: java, android, sdk, get, httprequest

This is a simple get request

and I have found out that the exception is caused by the

```
"HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);"
```

I don't know why, because it is copied from example.

I have tried different url, and still get the exception

if I print the exception, I will get null pointer exception

now I don't know how to find out the problem

anyone knows what the reason for this problem is?

here is the video [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvZxqidnWtY&feature=youtu.be) for this problem  -

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.v("cc",e.getMessage());
        Log.v("dd", "error");
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="so.lab4"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Lab4Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You should use `Log.v("dd", e)` to see the exception.

Comment: or better print the backstack

Comment: or use Log.v("dd", e.printStackTrace());

Comment: Code looks ok and the inet permission is added. But you should never make HTTP requests from your UI thread. Use Handler or AsyncTask

Comment: Log.v("dd", e)Log.v("dd", e.printStackTrace()), they also not work, because it only accept string parameter, now I use Log.v("dd", e.toString()) and get the NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too bad to make an HTTP connection in the event thread!

You should do this kind of work in a worker thread. If not, you are pausing the event thread from processing GUI events, and if the thread is held for more than 5 seconds, it will throw a nice ANR (AKA Application Not Responding) error.

Comment: Currently I found this to solve the problem, and I will use worker thread to handle it.
`code
 StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()     
 .detectDiskReads()     
 .detectDiskWrites()     
 .detectNetwork()   // or .detectAll() for all detectable problems     
 .penaltyLog()     
 .build());     
 StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder()     
 .detectLeakedSqlLiteObjects()     
 .detectLeakedClosableObjects()     
 .penaltyLog()     
 .penaltyDeath()     
 .build());`

Comment: Ok, but remember that `StrictMode` is not guaranteed to find everything you are doing wrong in the main thread, and sometimes warns about things that are absolutely normal. It is only available starting from Gingerbread, and you should use it only in debugging versions.